# jQuery toggle divs correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a section with questions and answers where I want only one question to be open at a time. So if you have 1 question open (answer is visible) then other answers will be closed.
I can't find a way to close the open div itself.

Example (clarification): If you click Question1, Answer1 shows. If you click Question1 again Answer1 doesn't hide (and it should). Only 1 Answer should be shown at a time. Class 'active' has to be applied only to the open question and removed from prevously open ones.

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hBnk/) of what I've done so far:

```
$('.tab-body').hide();

$('.tab-head').click(function () {

$('.tab-body').hide();
$(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').slideToggle();

$('.tab-head').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: whats your need? demo is working perfectly

Comment: It looks like your demo works as expected. What `div` you are referring to close?

Comment: Say you click Question 1. I want when you click it again to close Answer1. Now it's not doing it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9hBnk/2/ ???

Comment: @A.Wolff That works. Thank you. Your version works as well.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi No it doesn't.

Comment: @Mr.Alien You are a funny man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.tab-body').hide();

$('.tab-head').click(function () {
$('.tab-head').removeClass('active');

$('.tab-body').slideUp(); // Close all
var bb = $(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body');
if(bb.is(":visible")){
    bb.slideUp();
} else {
    bb.slideDown();
    $(this).addClass('active');
}   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/effone/9hBnk/12/

Comment: This suits me just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Revised class adding. Please check.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
$('.tab-body').hide();
$('.tab-head').click(function () {
    var tabBody = $(this).next();
    tabBody.slideToggle();
    $('.tab-body').not(tabBody).slideUp();
    $('.tab-head').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hBnk/10/)**

Comment: Thank you for the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.tab-body').hide();

$('.tab-head').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

        $(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').slideToggle();
        $('.tab-head').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.tab-body').hide();
        $(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').slideToggle();

        $('.tab-head').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

the hide in the click is not needed;

*edit rest of the divs will slide down

Comment: In this case opening another Question doesn't close the previous one. I need only one Answer to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    $('.tab-body').hide();

$('.tab-head').click(function () {
    var x=$(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body');
  $('.tab-body').not(x).hide();
  $(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').slideToggle();
  $('.tab-head').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hBnk/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest answer that i can give to you i think.

here is your jquery :

```
$('.tab-body').hide();
$('.tab-head').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').slideToggle();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.tab-body').hide();
        $(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').slideToggle();

        $('.tab-head').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9hBnk/7/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.tab-head').click(function () {

if ($(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').css("display") == "none") {
    $('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').slideUp();
    $(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').slideDown();
}
    else
    {
          $(this).parents('.tab-faq').find('.tab-body').slideUp();  
    }

    $('.tab-head').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9hBnk/11/